# Unit testing directive with controllerAs using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to Jasmine unit testing and this is the first time I am trying to test a directive with controller. The structure of my directive and controller is little different which I didn't see in any of the blogs or stackoverflow questions. I am struggling a bit to access the function _testSampleFunction() to test in my test cases. The downfall here is that I cannot change the architecture of directive and I want to write test cases accordingly. Any help would be appreciated!

Below is how my controller is defined :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp',[])
        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective()
{
        var directive ={
        template : '<div></div>',
        controller : myController,
        controllerAs : 'vm',
        scope: {},
        };

        myController.$inject =['$scope'];
        return directive;

    function myController($scope)
    {
        var vm = this;
        init();

        function init()
        {
            vm.TestSampleFunction = _testSampleFunction;
        }

        function _testSampleFunction()
        {
            return 'my directive';
        }

    }

}})(window.angular);
```

Here is the plunker (spec.js is included): [Demo Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/NfyscZUnpyLvslvH?preview)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive tests use the real controller, so you don't need to do any controller setup in the test.

I've updated your [Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/nsNcJOOyW2PCgONR?preview) with an example of a test through the view, but also how to get hold of the controller.

Directive tests are useful as you know the controller and view are tied up correctly - I mostly (apart from the odd occasion when I can't), test everything through the view (e.g. click on something in the page and check that the view is updated accordingly).

Comment: Thanks. That really worked!! In real time, I have to use templateURL. How should I configure it? I checked various posts some said to use $templateCache, $httpBackend, some suggested to use Karma.